# mysql subquery with multiple results error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, subquery

I have searched for a solution to this problem, some are close but cannot seem to find a solution. I have a table of "runs" with various information, one column being information on the company it applies to. I also have a table of companies storing all the information of the company. In the company column of the runs table, the company is identified by the "indexer" from the company table.

Now i have a search where you can search for any information about the run to find any number of records containing the search phrase, including company. Being the the company column of the run table just has in identifier number ie. 34, 23, 5 etc i need to also check for matches in the name column of the company table.

This is my query which works fine if only one company matches the search results. I need to return all company's that match.

`$sql_results = "SELECT * FROM runs WHERE name LIKE '%$searchname%' OR company = (SELECT indexer FROM companies WHERE name LIKE '%$searchname%' ) OR feild LIKE '%$searchname%' ORDER BY date_due";`

```
    while($result_results = @mysql_fetch_array($query_results))
    {
    $resultnm_array[]=$result_results['name'];
    $cmp_id = $result_results['company'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT name FROM companies WHERE indexer = '$cmp_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query2 = @mysql_query($sql2);
        $result2 = @mysql_fetch_array($query2);
        $resultcpy_array[]=$result2['name'];
    $resultfld_array[]=$result_results['feild'];
    $resultdt_array[]=$result_results['date_due'];
    $resultid_array[]=$result_results['indexer'];
    }
```

I am inputting results into an array and using the TBS template engine to create result tables etc. I am a bit of a novice so any help would be appreciated. From what I gather I need to use join. But i cant seem to make it work...

Comment: You should read about table normalization but take look to MySQL function FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not just use `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM runs 
WHERE name LIKE '%$searchname%' 
    OR company IN (
        SELECT indexer 
        FROM companies 
        WHERE name LIKE '%$searchname%' ) 
    OR feild LIKE '%$searchname%' 
ORDER BY date_due
```

Given your comments: "works fine if only one company matches the search results" -- that leads me to believe if multiple companies match the search criteria, the query fails because of the `=`.

---

Given your edits, you could make this simpler using a `JOIN` and you'd no longer require the additional select statement in your loop:

```
SELECT r.*, c.name
FROM runs r
    JOIN companies c on r.company = c.indexer
WHERE r.name LIKE '%$searchname%' 
    OR r.feild LIKE '%$searchname%' 
ORDER BY r.date_due
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using JOIN other then the additional SELECT statement? For me the first method is easier to read and therefore troubleshoot.

Comment: @Tyler -- yes, definitely.  Your current implementation requires multiple database hits.  First, return the results.  Then for each result, hit the database again to get their company name.  Using the `Join`, you can achieve this in a single db call.  Give it a try -- good luck!